# Android Studio LibGDX issues

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I'm a beginner in programming, I have found video tutorials on Youtube on how to program a simple game using Android Studio and LibGDX. The tutorials were going pretty good until part 34 ('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2R_e9wceHZA'). I have created the FloorEntity and the SpikeEntity ('Which in my project it's refered to StingEntity') When I run it, Android Studio complains with a series of errors. The errors are the following:

```
Error:(62, 24) Gradle: error: ';' expected
Error:(77, 22) Gradle: error: ';' expected
Error:(77, 34) Gradle: error: ';' expected
Error:(87, 23) Gradle: error: ';' expected
Error:(91, 1) Gradle: error: reached end of file while parsing
```

The code in the GameScreen.java is the following:

```
package com.mygame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.mygame.desktop.BaseScreen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.mygame.entities.FloorEntity;
import com.mygame.entities.PlayerEntity;
import com.mygame.entities.StingEntity;
import com.mygame.scene2d.ActorSting;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class GameScreen extends BaseScreen {

    private Stage stage;

    private World world;

    private PlayerEntity player;

    private List<FloorEntity> floorList = new ArrayList<FloorEntity>();

    private List<StingEntity> stingList = new ArrayList<StingEntity>();

    public GameScreen(MainGame game) {
        super(game);
        stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(640, 480));

        world = new World (new Vector2(0,-10), true);



    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        Texture playerTexture = game.getManager().get("blockman.png");
        Texture floorTexture = game.getManager().get("floor.png");
        Texture overfloorTexture = game.getManager().get("overfloor.png");
        Texture stingTexture = game.getManager().get("sting.png");

        floorList.add(new FloorEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture, 0, 1000, 1));
        stingList.add(new StingEntity(world, stingTexture, 6, 1));


        player = new PlayerEntity(world, playerTexture, new Vector2(1, 2));
        stage.addActor(player);
        for (FloorEntity floor : floorList) {
            stage.addActor(floor);
        }
        for (StingEntity sting : stingList) {
            stage.addActor(sting);
        }

        @Override
        public void hide () {
            player.detach();
            player.remove();
            for (FloorEntity floor : floorList) {
                floor.detach();
                floor.remove();
            }
            for (StingEntity sting : stingList) {
                stage.addActor(sting);
                sting.detach();
                sting.remove();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        super.render(delta);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.4f, 0.5f, 0.8f, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act();
        world.step(delta, 6, 2);
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose();{
        stage.dispose();
        world.dispose();
    }
}
```

Could somebody please help me with this? I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon after dispose()

```
@Override
public void dispose();{
    stage.dispose();
    world.dispose();
}
```

And you are trying do define a function inside of a function (multiple times). Your curly brackets are set incorrectly. Make sure to close a function before defining a new one.

Example:

```
@Override
public void show() {
...
       for (StingEntity sting : stingList) {
            stage.addActor(sting);
        }

} //<- inserted

@Override
public void hide () {
...
```